# Cant figure out why Classic ASP script is skipping first record in set

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, legacy-code

What I have here is part of a quite hacky Classic ASP (VBscript) script I need to pull data out so I can move it into another source. I am having trouble with it in that it appears to be skipping the first record in the piece it is pulling out. It seems to be fine until it hits a record with only one value, then it seems to pretend it's empty and moves on. If it has more than one record associated it renders them, skipping the first one, and moving on.

This script here shows the categories associated with a listing. (that part is not shown)

```
<%

If intCategoryID = "" Then
intCategoryID = request("ID")
End If
'Response.Write("Bus ID for Category: " & intCategoryID)
set rstCategories = nothing

intCountComma = 0
intFiveCat = 0

Set rstCategories = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )

If blnFr = 1 Then
strSQL = "SELECT ID, Case Name_Displayed_L2 When '' Then Name_Displayed Else Name_Displayed_L2 End As Name_Displayed, Attraction_Sub_Types.FriendlyURL"

Else
strSQL = "SELECT ID, Name_Displayed, Attraction_Sub_Types.FriendlyURL"

End If

strSQL = strSQL & " From Attraction_Sub_Types Inner Join Attractions_Attraction_Sub_Types_Link ON Attractions_Attraction_Sub_Types_Link.Sub_TypeID = Attraction_Sub_Types.ID"
strSQL = strSQL & " Where Attractions_Attraction_Sub_Types_Link.AttractionID = '" & intCategoryID & "'"



set rstCategories = Conn.execute(strSQL)

If Not rstCategories.BOF And Not rstCategories.EOF Then
rstCategories.MoveFirst
'Do While (Not rstCategories.EOF AND intFiveCat <= 5 )
Do While (intFiveCat <= 5 )
intFiveCat = intFiveCat + 1

If Not rstCategories.EOF Then

If intCountComma <> 0 Then  

strNameDisplayed = rstCategories("Name_Displayed")

strSQL2 = "SELECT ID, Name_Displayed, Attraction_Types.FriendlyURL"
strSQL2 = strSQL2 & " From Attraction_Types Inner Join Attraction_Types_Sub_Types_Link ON Attraction_Types_Sub_Types_Link.TypeID = Attraction_Types.ID"
strSQL2 = strSQL2 & " Where Attraction_Types_Sub_Types_Link.Sub_TypeID = '" & rstCategories("ID") & "'"
set rstMaincats = Conn.execute(strSQL2)

If Not rstMaincats.EOF Then

strMainName = rstMaincats("Name_Displayed")
Else
strMainName = "unsorted"
End If

Response.Write("<td>")

%>

<%=strMainName%>-><%=strNameDisplayed%>

<% Response.Write("</td>")  


    Else
        intCountComma = intCountComma + 1
    End If

  rstCategories.MoveNext



'Do While ( intFiveCat <= 5 )

'Response.Write("<td>")

'Response.Write("</td>")

'intFiveCat = intFiveCat + 1
'Loop

Else
%>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<%
End If

    Loop

Else 
Do While (intFiveCat <= 4 )
intFiveCat = intFiveCat + 1
%>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<%
Loop
End If



If rstCategories.State = adStateOpen Then
rstCategories.Close
End If

Set rstCategories = Nothing
%>
```

This image is the output of this piece: http://i.imgur.com/BAwSxWk.jpg you the ones that show blanks, are ones that should have 1 category instead are showing none, while the others are showing the second category and onward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you specified the first row from rstCategories to be skipped ::  _If intCountComma <> 0 Then : ya-di-ya-di : else : intCountComma = intCountComma + 1
   :  End If :   rstCategories.MoveNext_ (in other words, the ya-di-ya-di is not done for the first row)

Comment: That was it! - Can't believe i missed it!... Thank you so much

You should post as an answer below so I can mark as solved.

Comment: A good way to debug it when concat string is to do a Response.Write("<p>" & strSQL & "</p>") to figure out what it tries to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you specified the first row from rstCategories to be skipped

```
If intCountComma <> 0 Then 
    'ya-di-ya-di 
else 
    intCountComma = intCountComma + 1 
End If 
rstCategories.MoveNext
```

*(in other words, the ya-di-ya-di is not done for the first row)*

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this solved my problem exactly. Turns out that was a rouge if condition that was not even needed for what I was trying to do. Removing it fixed the issue.